# Удалить последний объект, соответствующий свойству из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
    const arr = [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "category: 7,
     },
     {
      "id": 2,
      "category: 6,
     },
     {
      "id": 3,
      "category: 7,
     },
     {
      "id": 4,
      "category: 6,
     },
    ]
```

**Хочу удалить последний из категории 7**

Результат должен быть таким:

```
const arr = [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "category: 7,
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "category: 6,
 },
 {
  "id": 4,
  "category: 6,
 },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, что изменения массива должны проходить по месту (не создавая новый массив). Первое, что нужно сделать найти индекс элемента `findLastIndex`,а затем воспользоваться `splice` для удаления элемента с этим индексом.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": 7,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": 6,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "category": 7,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "category": 6,
  },
]

const index = arr.findLastIndex(e => e.category === 7)
if (index >= 0) arr.splice(index, 1)
console.log(arr)
```